# Program is Inserting node after first element in circular linklist why?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

[image]i am trying to write a simple circular link list program where i want to insert node at the start.

1: first i created list.
2: then i want to insert element at beginning.

when i am trying to output its displaying the element is inserted after first element, which i am not expecting .

i tried a lot of post if someone face the same issue but no fruitful results.

can some one help me in this ..

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct llist
{
int data;
struct llist *next;
}list;

void createlist(list**, int);
void InsertAtbeg(list**, int);
void display(list*);
int main()
{
list *node = NULL;
int i,n;
printf("\n enter no of elements:-");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    createlist(&node, i);
}

display(node);
InsertAtbeg(&node, 100);
printf("\n elements after insertion at beg :-");
display(node);
return 0;
}

void createlist(list **H, int x)
{
list *p,*r;
if(*H==NULL)
{
    p = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->data =x;
    p->next = p;
    *H = p;
}
else
{
    r = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    r ->data =x;
    p->next =r;
    r->next =*H;
    p=r;

}
  }

 void InsertAtbeg(list**H, int x)
    {
        list* p,*r;
        r=*H;
        p= (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
p->data =x;
p->next = r->next;
r->next = p;
*H=r;
}

void display(list* H)
{
  list *p;
  if(H!=NULL)
  {
     p = H;
    while (p->next !=  H)
    {
        printf("\n elements in list are:- %d", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n elements in list are:- %d", p->data);
   }
}
```

Comment: The very first thing I'd do is add `stdlib.h` to your include list, since you clearly use it. Second. `struct list *next;` there is no `struct list` in your code, there is only `struct llist` and `list` aliased to that. Third, `p->next =r;` in `createlist()` - um, `p` isn't initialized on that statement, so your program invokes undefined behavior. Start with fixing those.

Comment: What: `typedef struct llist
{
int data;
struct list` ?

Comment: corrected it still getting same output...

Comment: If you corrected everything in that laundry list (including the third item in particular) and the results are still the same, then update your posted code and I'll drop my comments and we can move on. Somehow, I'm hesitant to believe #3 was handled that quickly, however.

Comment: updated code ..apart from p isn't initialized on that statement...  @WhozCraig  my concern is regarding the logic InsertAtbeg() function..can u please address that

Comment: i dont think you have to use double pointer when you create a node & insert a node. it is better if you have a head node as global pointer.

Comment: Actually i don't want to keep track of header node updates by using simple pointer ..so just trying the code with double pointers..

Comment: @sanjeev `main()` invokes `createlist`, which by-its definition is invoking *undefined behavior*. it's pointless to consider much beyond that until it is resolved. One step at a time. That problem is *not* trivial with a single-linked circular list, btw.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have make the `InsertAtbeg` to return the new node added and set it as the head and pass it to the `display`. Instead, what you are doing is passing the old head, which is clearly incorrect.

Add the required headers

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
```

Your `createlist` is improper (I did not inspect it but wrote a quick `for` loop inside the `main`).

```
    int main() {
        list *head = malloc(sizeof(list));
        list *node = head;
        int i,n;
        printf("\n enter no of elements: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            node->data = i;
            if (i<n) {
                node->next = malloc(sizeof(list));
                node = node->next;
            } if (i==n)
                  node->next = head;
        }

        display(head);
        list* I = InsertAtbeg(node, 100);
        printf("\n elements after insertion at beg :-");
        display(I); // here you need to pass the new node "I" as head
        return 0;
   }
```

Now the `InsertAtBeg` you can actually pass the `last` node but not the `head`. You can get the head from the `last->next` and make it return the new `head`.

```
    list* InsertAtbeg(list *Last, int x) {
        list *Head = Last->next;
        list *Insert = malloc(sizeof(list));
        Last->next = Insert;
        Insert->data = x;
        Insert->next = Head;
        return Insert;
    }
```

The display function I left it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a copy of your code. I've added comments to explain what is wrong.

```
void InsertAtbeg(list**H, int x)
{
    list* p,*r;
    r=*H;
    p= (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->data =x;
    p->next = r->next;  // wrong: must  be p->next = r as the new element 
                        // shall point to the current head
    r->next = p;        // wrong: delete this line - no need for changing 
                        // next of current head
    *H=r;               // wrong: must be *H = p so the new element becomes head

    // wrong: you are not done yet. you miss that the last element 
    //        shall have its next pointer updated
    //        so that it points to the new element
}
```

BTW: Your `createlist` has undefined behavior as p is not initialized